# Reduce() after filter() in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, bigdata, reduce

I have question about two functions in python: reduce() and filter().
Can we use reduce() after filter()?

I used boston datasets in sklearn.

```
x = load_boston()
x_target = x.target
xx = filter(lambda x: x > 20, x_target)
```

And it's working fine.
Next I want use reduce() function to sum up values in xx.

```
from functools import reduce
xxx = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, xx)
```

I got error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-062fcc861672> in <module>()
      1 from functools import reduce
----> 2 xxx = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, xx)

TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `filter()` produces an iterator, which you can use in `reduce()` just fine. But your error indicates you have *already consumed all the values from the filter*. Filters are not re-usable, you need to create it anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `filter()` object in `reduce()` just fine:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> values = range(10, 30)
>>> filtered = filter(lambda x: x > 20, values)
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, filtered)
225
```

However, a `filter()` object is an *iterator*; it will yield filtered values on demand, and when it reaches the end *won't yield anything else*. So you need to make sure you don't empty it before you pass it to `reduce()`:

```
>>> filtered = filter(lambda x: x > 20, values)
>>> filtered
<filter object at 0x10ee64ac8>
>>> list(filtered)
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, filtered)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Re-create the `filter()` object when you need to re-use it in multiple places.

Comment: Is the error happens in Python 3? because in 2.7 `filter` returns a list, was it changed to a `filter object`?

Comment: @Vinny: yes, Python 3 `filter()` does not return a list, filtering takes place on demand.

Answer (score 0):

That means the filter function returns an empty list over your list. Here you have an example:

```
sample = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, sample)
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8]
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, sample))
>>> 20
```

So, your code should work.

This is python 2.7. Should be different in python 3+

**EDIT**: with python3

```
 from functools import reduce
 sample = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
 f = filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, sample)
 reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, f)
 >>> 20
```

Works the same way ; )

Comment: Yes, it is different in Python 3, and that's the root of the problem the OP has.